# Is this ellipsis grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, ellipses, repetition, sentence-ends

Which of these sentence constructions is correct? The only difference is the last word.

> 1. Sometimes questioning others' assumptions is not the hardest part of being an activist; the hardest part is questioning our own.
> 2. Sometimes questioning others' assumptions is not the hardest part of being an activist; the hardest part is questioning our own assumptions.

Comment: Both are correct. The first one stands out in vigour and brevity.

Answer (score 2):

These two sentences are both correct in a sense that they are grammatical. In the first sentence, the word *[own](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/own?showCookiePolicy=true)* is used as a [pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronoun), while in the second sentence it plays the role of an [adjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective).

> **own**
>
> [*pronoun*] that which belongs to oneself ⇒ the car is his own; I have reasons of my own
>
> [*adjective*] belonging, relating, or peculiar to oneself or itself (used to strengthen a preceding possessive) ⇒ his own book, her own idea

The first sentence would be a better choice of expression. It is always good to omit words that are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fault to be found in either. The first seems more elegant.